# "Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-priority-highest" using org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, debugging

While I'm trying to access any of the org-agenda options or commands! I always get this error `Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-priority-highest` 
and the list shows nothing even though I've set `org-agenda-files` correctly

Answer (score 2):

The current name for the highest priority value is `org-highest-priority` instead of `org-priority-highest`. They changed the names in January 2020 in [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/1de5e80adf44db60c042979a902ca0de64975a39). An alias was added for the old name, but there was a [bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg127127.html) in the way it was done.

This bug appears to be in 9.3.6 and fixed in 9.3.7. Try updating your `org-mode`.

Comment: I use `straight.el` as the package manger so I got latest commit in the repo!

Comment: Maybe you have a mixed install? There are issues upgrading `org-mode` when it's already loaded. What if you uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: I tried and uninstalling and reinstalling but the problem persists

Comment: In that case I would first restart with `emacs -q` and do the minimum to reproduce the error.  Use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to get a backtrace to the point in the code generating the error.  If the error is in `org-mode` you can submit a bug report

Comment: On the contrary: `org-priority-highest` is the official name going forwards; the other one is an alias for backward compatibility. The title of the commit is "Rename `org-x-priority` functions and variables to `org-priority-x`".

Answer (score 2):

It's an problem of `straight.el` see [here](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#the-wrong-version-of-my-package-was-loaded). I solved using a solution given by one user in the [github isssue](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el/issues/211).

Thanks for answering and helping me!

Comment: whats your org load strategy in straight now? its still not working for me,

Comment: can you please add the solution to the content of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred for me when using `straight.el` to load various `org` packages. Org being a dependency leads straight to cloning a current version of it into its local repo. Using agenda then created the same error message of `Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-priority-highest`.

In my case(Emacs 27.1, Org 9.3), a simple solution was to tell `straight.el` to use Emacs' standard built-in `org` version instead  by using the `:type built-in` directive. I placed the following before declaring any other org-related packages:

```
(straight-use-package '(org :type built-in))
```