# Using org-roam-capture throws error: Symbol's function definition is void: org-fold-show-all

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-roam

I am using org-roam and the problem occurs when I try to use an org-roam-capture template.
The capture template is for creating org-roam-nodes from citations using citar. It is based on [this](https://jethrokuan.github.io/org-roam-guide/) blog post by the author of org-roam.
The exact function from the blog post worked in my old configuration. I suspect that some packages have changed, as I had to do some changes in order to use citar.

I cannot figure out if it is due to some incompatibility between some of the packages, or if my configuration is wrong.
In case it is relevant, I use straight.el with use-package and the load order and versions of the relevant packages is:

- org version 9.5.2
- org-roam version 2.2.2
- citar

I am using Emacs 28.1 running on windows 11.

I appreciate any help, as this is the first time I have done any significant hacking on my configuration.

The function from my configuration:

```lisp
  (defun org-roam-node-from-cite (keys-entries)
      (interactive (list (citar-select-refs :multiple nil)))
      (let ((title  (citar-format--entry "${author editor} :: ${title}"
                     (citar-get-entry keys-entries))))
    (org-roam-capture- :templates
               '(("r" "reference" plain "%?" :if-new
                  (file+head "reference/${citekey}.org"
                     ":PROPERTIES:
  :ROAM_REFS: [cite:@${citekey}]
  :END:
  ,#+title: ${title}\n")
                  :immediate-finish t
                  :unnarrowed t))
               :info (list :citekey (car keys-entries))
               :node (org-roam-node-create :title title)
               :props '(:finalize find-file))))
```

The backtrace:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture template ‘r’: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-fold-show-all")
  error("Capture template `%s': %s" "r" "Symbol’s function definition is void: org-fold-show-all")
  org-capture(nil "r")
  org-roam-capture-(:templates (("r" "reference" plain "%?" :if-new (file+head "reference/${citekey}.org" ":PROPERTIES:\n:ROAM_REFS: [cite:@${citekey}]\n:END:\n...") :immediate-finish t :unnarrowed t)) :info (:citekey "rougierSiliconSoulVain") :node #s(org-roam-node :file nil :file-title nil :file-hash nil :file-atime nil :file-mtime nil :id "62250114-c23e-45a0-8279-db689cdbeea6" :level nil :point nil :todo nil :priority nil :scheduled nil :deadline nil :title " :: " :properties nil :olp nil :tags nil :aliases nil :refs nil) :props (:finalize find-file :call-location #<marker at 1 in *scratch*>))
  (let ((title (citar-format--entry "${author editor} :: ${title}" (citar-get-entry keys-entries)))) (org-roam-capture- :templates '(("r" "reference" plain "%?" :if-new (file+head "reference/${citekey}.org" ":PROPERTIES:\n:ROAM_REFS: [cite:@${citekey}]\n:END:\n...") :immediate-finish t :unnarrowed t)) :info (list :citekey (car keys-entries)) :node (record 'org-roam-node nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil title nil nil nil nil nil) :props '(:finalize find-file :call-location #<marker at 1 in *scratch*>)))
  org-roam-node-from-cite(("rougierSiliconSoulVain"))
  funcall-interactively(org-roam-node-from-cite ("rougierSiliconSoulVain"))
  command-execute(org-roam-node-from-cite)
```

Here is the capture template

```lisp
    ("r" "reference" plain "%?"
     :if-new
     (file+head "reference/${title}.org" "#+title: ${title}\n")
     :immediate-finish tn
     :unnarrowed t)
```

A node is created but it is incomplete:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ROAM_REFS: [cite:@rougierSiliconSoulVain]
:ID:       c24c40e3-ca1f-4981-b05e-fcda2021a3ee
:END:
#+title:  ::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of org, and is similar to
[this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58994/symbol-s-value-as-variable-is-void-org-priority-highest-using-org-agenda).

Straight.el clones the org repo, and uses that.
The solution was to use the org version that is built in to emacs, which can be done as described in the straight.el [docs](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el#how-can-i-use-the-built-in-version-of-a-package).

```
(use-package org :straight (:type built-in))
```

Once I did this, the problem described above disappeared.